# yii2 Как сформировать запрос?

Tags: mysql, yii2, activerecord

Есть рабочий запрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`id_timestamp`) as `ids`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_user_aswer` WHERE `id_timestamp` = `ids`) as `c` FROM `test_user_aswer` WHERE `id_user`='2'
```

Как с помощью **ActiveRecord** его записать?

Пробовал так:

```
$query = UserAnswer::find(); 
$times = $query->select([
    'ids' => 'id_timestamp',
    'c' => $query->select(['COUNT(`id_timestamp`)'])->where(['id_timestamp' => 'ids'])->createCommand()->getRawSql()
    ])
  ->distinct()
  ->where(['id_user' => $id_user])
  ->asArray()
  ->all();
```

Но выдает ошибку, что не правильный запрос

Comment: Можно текст ошибки, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи.

Запросы можно объединить.

```
$query1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select("id, category_id AS type, name")
  ->from('post')
  ->limit(10);

$query2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select('id, type, name')
  ->from('user')
  ->limit(10);

$query1->union($query2);
```

Можно объединить через join

```
$query->leftJoin('post', 'post.user_id = user.id');
```

В ActiveRecord тоже всё это можно использовать.

```
$customers = Customer::find()
  ->select('customer.*')
  ->leftJoin('order', '`order`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id`')
  ->where(['order.status' => Order::STATUS_ACTIVE])
  ->with('orders')
  ->all();
```

Подробности [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md) и [тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-active-record.md).

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил данный вопрос, проблема была в том, что YII не брал в дужки запрос в SELECT. Сделал так:

```
    $query = UserAnswer::find();
    $times = $query->select([
                'ids' => 'id_timestamp',
                'c' => '('.$query->select(['COUNT(`id_timestamp`)'])
                            ->where('`id_timestamp` = `ids`')
                            ->createCommand()
                            ->getRawSql().')'
            ])
        ->distinct()
        ->where(['id_user' => $id_user])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Мда... Ну раз Вас устраивает "костыль" на "костылях" - Ваше право...